# Can your Mathematica do the following integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, backslide

**Backslide introduced in v10 and fixed in v10.4.1.**

---

I was trying to do the following integral in Mathematica:

```
Integrate[(z-2) PolyLog[2,z]Log[1-z]/z^3,z]
```

What I got was:

[image]

The result after FullSimplify:
[image]

While on my friends' computers, Using mathematica, both of them were able to get the result of the integral immediately, which is  [image]

Could anyone tell what went wrong with my Mathematica or what setting should I change? I'm using the student edition, Version 10.3.1.

The other weird thing is Mathematica is actually able to do the following integrals separately:
[image]

And I tried just now, Wolfram Alpha is actually able to do this integral:[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28x-2%29+PolyLog%5B2%2Cz%5D+Log%5B1-z%5D%2Fz%5E3%2Cz%5D](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28x-2%29%20PolyLog%5B2%2Cz%5D%20Log%5B1-z%5D%2Fz%5E3%2Cz%5D)

Comment: Verified on my 10.3.1. A FullSimplify doesn't help. I took the derivative of the answer provided, and indeed it gives the integrand. Yet 10.3.1 can't do the integral.

Comment: Ditto @MarkAdler's comment. What was your friends machine and which version of Mathematica?

Comment: I actually tried it on my 10.1.0, and it's not working, then I updated my Mathematica to 10.3.1, and it's still not work.

Comment: One of them is using Macbook and the other one is using Windows.

Comment: It would be good to know machine type, OS and Version of Mathematica.

Comment: Please have a look at the last figure I added.

Comment: Your friend is probably using v9. BTW v8.0.4 can't solve the integral at all.

Comment: Here is a workaround, since it can do it term by term. `f = (z - 2) PolyLog[2, z] Log[1 - z]/z^3;Simplify[Integrate[#, z] & /@ Expand[f]]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nzyNc.png) Mathematica seems to be really confused about something here.

Comment: @Nasser - Use `FullSimplify` vice `Simplify` to get a shorter form.

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(*  "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)"  *)

f[z_] = (z - 2) PolyLog[2, z] Log[1 - z]/z^3;

fi[z_] = Integrate[#, z] & /@ (f[z] // Expand) //
  FullSimplify

(*  (1/(6*z^2))*
   (z^2*(Pi^2 - 24*ArcTanh[
               1 - 2*z]) + 
      12*z*Log[1 - z] - 3*(-1 + z)^2*
        Log[1 - z]^2 - 
      6*(z*(1 + z) + (-1 + z)*
             Log[1 - z])*PolyLog[2, z])  *)

D[fi[z], z] == f[z] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: It seems that `Expand` is expanding the integrand into the two terms that the OP points out in the question can be integrated. (I just noticed it was also pointed out by [Nasser](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102815/can-your-mathematica-do-the-following-integral/102818#comment279318_102815). Oh, well, interesting.)

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Dear Bob, on my machine Win7/Mma10.3 the operator `Integrate[#, z] & /@ (f[z])` already nicely makes the job. However, strangely seemingly the operator `Integrate[f[z], z]`  that is very close the the previous one, returns the expression only partially evaluated. Could you kindly comment on the reasons of such a behavior?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - the direct integration encounters a pattern in the integrand (or intermediate step) for which it does not have a rule/algorithm. Mapping onto the component parts provides simpler forms for which it has the necessary rules/algorithms. Presumably there is some reason why Mma doesn't automatically do this mapping (efficiency or edge cases where it would complicate dealing with singularities?). I view this as similar to the way that use of `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` is left to the user's discretion: apply as necessary.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thank you, good to know.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround to get an antiderivative:

```
ad = Integrate[(z - 2) PolyLog[2, z] Log[1 - z]/z^3, {z, 1/2, x}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False]
(*
  (1/(24 x^2))(-48 (-1 + x) x Log[1 - x] - 12 (-1 + x)^2 Log[1 - x]^2 + 
    x^2 (-24 (Log[2]^2 + Log[2]^3 - 2 Log[4]) + π^2 (6 + Log[16]) + 
       48 Log[x]) - 24 (x (1 + x) + (-1 + x) Log[1 - x]) PolyLog[2, x])
*)
```

Numeric checks against `NIntegrate`:

```
(* For 0 < x < 1 *)
{Hold[NIntegrate[(z - 2) PolyLog[2, z] Log[1 - z]/z^3, {z, 1/2, #}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 20] & /@ x],
 ad} /. x -> RandomReal[1, 10, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // ReleaseHold
Subtract @@ %
(*
  {{-4.3165400356514353565,  1.3300977020665013728,   1.2997863764381825926,
     1.6292844375810144296,  0.82000829487649921791, -2.6361785894927865795,
    -1.8584257847053658824, -3.3417797354652695764,   0.44399367232706982999, 
    -1.4571741116926172876}, 
   {-4.31654003565143536,    1.330097702066501373,    1.299786376438182593, 
     1.629284437581014430,   0.820008294876499218,   -2.636178589492786580, 
    -1.858425784705365882,  -3.34177973546526958,     0.443993672327069830, 
    -1.457174111692617288}}

  {0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-19, 0.*10^-19, 0.*10^-19, 0.*10^-19,
   0.*10^-19, 0.*10^-19, 0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-19, 0.*10^-19}
*)

(* For -2 < x < 0 *)
{Hold[NIntegrate[(z - 2) PolyLog[2, z] Log[1 - z]/z^3, {z, -1, #},
   WorkingPrecision -> 20] & /@ x],
 ad - (ad /. x -> -1)} /. x -> RandomReal[{-2, 0}, 10, WorkingPrecision -> 20] //
  ReleaseHold;
Subtract @@ %
(*
{0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 
 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 
 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 
 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 
 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I}
*)
```

---

Another way to get an antiderivative:

```
Integrate[(z - 2) PolyLog[2, z] Log[1 - z]/z^3, z] /. 
   HoldPattern@Integrate[i_, v_] :> (Integrate[#, v] & /@ Expand[i]) //
   FullSimplify
(*
  (1/(6 z^2))(3 (4 - 3 z) z Log[1 - z] - 3 (-1 + z)^2 Log[1 - z]^2 + 
    z^2 (-3 + 2 π^2 - 3 Log[-1 + z] + 12 Log[z]) - 
    6 (z (1 + z) + (-1 + z) Log[1 - z]) PolyLog[2, z])
*)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your way of doing another integral :Integrate[(24 (1 - z)^a)/((-1 + (1 - z)^\a)^2 z) /. 
   HoldPattern@Integrate[i_, v_] :> (Integrate[#, v] & /@ Expand[i]) //
   FullSimplify, but it seems that the result it gave isn't the integral. Could you tell me when your command is applicable? Thank you so much!